# Update to 3.5. "MySQL couldn't be started. Please check the log file for more information."

Tags: mysql

I just updated MAMP PRO to 3.5 from 3.4.

Starting up the server it says "MySQL couldn't be started. Please check the log file for more information." the Apache started but not MySQL. Anyone is having this issue with the new update?

Here is the logs:

```
151225 10:34:08 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from 

/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql
151225 10:34:08 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/ is case insensitive
151225 10:34:08 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
151225 10:34:08 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151225 10:34:08 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
151225 10:34:08 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
151225 10:34:08 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
151225 10:34:08 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
151225 10:34:08 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
151225 10:34:08 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
151225 10:34:08 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
151225 10:34:08 [ERROR] Aborting

151225 10:34:08 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

151225 10:34:08 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
151225 10:35:41 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql
151225 10:35:41 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/ is case insensitive
151225 10:35:41 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
151225 10:35:41 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151225 10:35:41 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
151225 10:35:41 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
151225 10:35:41 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
151225 10:35:41 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
151225 10:35:41 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
151225 10:35:41 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
151225 10:35:41 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
151225 10:35:41 [ERROR] Aborting

151225 10:35:41 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

151225 10:35:41 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
151225 10:37:41 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql
151225 10:37:41 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/ is case insensitive
151225 10:37:41 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
151225 10:37:41 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151225 10:37:41 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
151225 10:37:41 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
151225 10:37:41 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
151225 10:37:41 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
151225 10:37:41 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
151225 10:37:41 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
151225 10:37:41 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
151225 10:37:41 [ERROR] Aborting

151225 10:37:41 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

151225 10:37:41 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
151225 10:45:11 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql
151225 10:45:11 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/ is case insensitive
151225 10:45:11 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
151225 10:45:11 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151225 10:45:11 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
151225 10:45:11 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
151225 10:45:11 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
151225 10:45:11 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
151225 10:45:11 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
151225 10:45:11 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
151225 10:45:11 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
151225 10:45:11 [ERROR] Aborting

151225 10:45:11 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

151225 10:45:11 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
151225 10:51:22 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql
151225 10:51:22 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/ is case insensitive
151225 10:51:22 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
151225 10:51:22 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151225 10:51:22 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
151225 10:51:22 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
151225 10:51:22 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
151225 10:51:22 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
151225 10:51:22 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
151225 10:51:22 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
151225 10:51:22 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
151225 10:51:22 [ERROR] Aborting

151225 10:51:22 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

151225 10:51:22 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
151225 10:56:48 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql
151225 10:56:48 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/ is case insensitive
151225 10:56:48 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
151225 10:56:48 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151225 10:56:48 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
151225 10:56:48 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
151225 10:56:48 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
151225 10:56:48 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
151225 10:56:48 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
151225 10:56:48 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
151225 10:56:48 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
151225 10:56:48 [ERROR] Aborting

151225 10:56:48 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

151225 10:56:48 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

Answer (score 3):

On OS X you can just delete the ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 files located in: /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db

Then your MySQL should start normal. MAMP will generate some new ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 files for you.

Answer (score 2):

> InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 bytes
>   InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!

The upgrade seems to have changed my.cnf without giving you a chance to fix it.

In particular, `innodb_log_file_size` must not be changed without taking extra actions.

Plan A:  If you can find the old my.cnf, put it in place; MySQL should come up ok.

Plan B:  Find out how big ib_logfile0 is and modify my.cnf to include

```
innodb_log_file_size = 50331648
```

(You probably had that value, 48M, in the my.cnf before upgrading.)

Plan C:  There are other approaches; but let's try them first.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you have another version of Mysql installed than the MAMP one. Try to uninstall MAMP and Mysql, then reinstall MAMP, it should works.

Answer (score 0):

MAMP > File > Edit Template > MySQL used version

Search: `innodb_force_recovery`

Remove # and set: `innodb_force_recovery = 1`